# Split Pandas Column Values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this. I want to flatten out the Final_Column data so that if there are two data (separated by a comma), the row gets duplicated with the second/third/fourth data in the next duplicated row.

```
    Query_Name  Market  Details Final_Column
    0   dummy_queryname dummy_market    23.65316176 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    1   dummy_queryname dummy_market    45.80583529 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '2684157'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}] 
    2   dummy_queryname dummy_market    51.36167825 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '2684157'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}] 
    3   dummy_queryname dummy_market    19.88567955 [{'name': 'relevant_data1', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892601'}, {'name': 'relevant_data2', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892718'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]  relevant_data1,relevant_data2
    4   dummy_queryname dummy_market    35.27507755 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    5   dummy_queryname dummy_market    61.93743196 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    6   dummy_queryname dummy_market    36.13855036 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    7   dummy_queryname dummy_market    14.48145401 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    8   dummy_queryname dummy_market    71.63468683 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    9   dummy_queryname dummy_market    54.11091504 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    10  dummy_queryname dummy_market    75.50864821 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    11  dummy_queryname dummy_market    99.03587932 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    12  dummy_queryname dummy_market    90.00233695 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    13  dummy_queryname dummy_market    71.77914123 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2790116', 'id': '2790148'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}] 
    14  dummy_queryname dummy_market    84.74331618 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    15  dummy_queryname dummy_market    22.85314775 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    16  dummy_queryname dummy_market    38.54872031 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    17  dummy_queryname dummy_market    79.04120263 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    18  dummy_queryname dummy_market    92.68911593 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
    19  dummy_queryname dummy_market    34.7022886  [{'name': 'relevant_data3', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892659'}, {'name': 'relevant_data4', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892667'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '2684157'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]   relevant_data3,relevant_data4
```

So it would look like this (duplicates at 4 and 21):

```
Query_Name  Market  Details Final_Column
0   dummy_queryname dummy_market    23.65316176 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
1   dummy_queryname dummy_market    45.80583529 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '2684157'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}] 
2   dummy_queryname dummy_market    51.36167825 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '2684157'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}] 
3   dummy_queryname dummy_market    19.88567955 [{'name': 'relevant_data1', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892601'}, {'name': 'relevant_data2', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892718'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]  relevant_data1
4   dummy_queryname dummy_market    19.88567955 [{'name': 'relevant_data1', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892601'}, {'name': 'relevant_data2', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892718'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]  relevant_data2
5   dummy_queryname dummy_market    35.27507755 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
6   dummy_queryname dummy_market    61.93743196 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
7   dummy_queryname dummy_market    36.13855036 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
8   dummy_queryname dummy_market    14.48145401 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
9   dummy_queryname dummy_market    71.63468683 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
10  dummy_queryname dummy_market    54.11091504 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
11  dummy_queryname dummy_market    75.50864821 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
12  dummy_queryname dummy_market    99.03587932 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
13  dummy_queryname dummy_market    90.00233695 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
14  dummy_queryname dummy_market    71.77914123 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2790116', 'id': '2790148'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}] 
15  dummy_queryname dummy_market    84.74331618 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
16  dummy_queryname dummy_market    22.85314775 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
17  dummy_queryname dummy_market    38.54872031 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
18  dummy_queryname dummy_market    79.04120263 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
19  dummy_queryname dummy_market    92.68911593 [{'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]    
20  dummy_queryname dummy_market    34.7022886  [{'name': 'relevant_data3', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892659'}, {'name': 'relevant_data4', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892667'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '2684157'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]   relevant_data3
21  dummy_queryname dummy_market    34.7022886  [{'name': 'relevant_data3', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892659'}, {'name': 'relevant_data4', 'parentName': 'relevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2892458', 'id': '2892667'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'irrelevant_scrape', 'parentId': '2662610', 'id': '2684157'}, {'name': 'dummy_data', 'parentName': 'dummy_data', 'parentId': '2517840', 'id': '2565351'}]   relevant_data4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to find out the rows at which there are multiple relevant data in the 'First_Column' section and multiplicate those rows by the amount of relevant data existing in that row.

For simplicity, suppose you have your dictionary data in Final_Column have the structure `[{'relevantness': <0 or 1>, 'data': <any number>},...]`

I would suggest you to first write a function that will operate on every element in the Final_Column and find the amount of relevant data there are. e.g.:

```
def find_relevants(dctlist):
    count = 0
    for it in dctlist:
        relness = it['relevantness'] 
        if relness > 0:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Then, first use it to create another column with the extracted relevant data counts:

```
df['relcount'] = df['Final_Column'].map(find_relevants)
```

After that it's only a matter of building another dataframe by duplicating the rows with the corresponding relcounts. ([DataFrame docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html))

Here I did it by traversing the dataframe and building a list of rows and then using them to build a final dataframe. This is probably not efficient at all, so if that's one of your concerns you might want to consider another way of doing this.

Assuming you already have your input dataframe `df`:

```
# temporary accumulation list initialization
rowlist = []
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    # df.iterrows() lets you traverse rows as pandas Series.
    count = row['relcount']
    if count > 1:
        # [it]*i -> [it,it,it,...] : has i elements
        rowlist.extend([row] * count)
    else:
        rowlist.append(row)
# reset_index fixes the index duplicates.
finaldf = pandas.DataFrame(rowlist).reset_index()

# we drop the relcount column as we no longer need it
finaldf.drop('relcount',axis=1,inplace=True)
print(finaldf)
```

## Edit 1:

After reading your comment, I made these changes. I don't know how you get your dataframe, but this looks like something that should have been done when constructing the dataframe at first. Anyway:

Assuming `df` is your pre-constructed dataframe, you just need to iterate over your dataframe and construct rows again. There might be a higher level way to do this, but it's really trivial doing it this way:

```
# Accumulator for new rows
rowlist = []
# Iterating over rows
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    # list in question
    data = row['Final_Column']
    # data count in the list
    datacount = len(data)
    if datacount < 2:
        # we pass the row as is and continue iteration
        rowlist.append(row)
        continue

    for dat in data:
        # make a duplicate
        newrow = row.copy()
        # change the relevant column with extracted data
        newrow['Final_Column'] = dat
        rowlist.append(newrow)

# Create final dataframe
finaldf = pandas.DataFrame(rowlist)

# Reset the index, note that drop=True drops the old index instead of
# creating a new column and moving it there.
finaldf.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

print(finaldf)
```

## Extra

Here I provide the full scripts I wrote to test the solution:

### Data generation

```
# prep.py
import pandas
import random

headers = "Query_Name Market Details Final_Column".split()

arbnumgen = lambda: random.normalvariate(50,25)

datagen = lambda relev: {'relevantness': relev, 'data': arbnumgen()}

def genfinalcolumn(relcount, irrelcount):
    relevants = [datagen(1) for i in range(relcount)]
    irrelevants = [datagen(0) for i in range(irrelcount)]
    shuffled = relevants + irrelevants
    random.shuffle(shuffled)

    return shuffled


def generate_data():
    dummy_qname = "dummy_qn"
    dummy_market = "dummy_m"

    irrels = [genfinalcolumn(0,1) for i in range(10)]
    rels1 = [genfinalcolumn(1,1) for i in range(3)] # 1 relevant
    rels2 = [genfinalcolumn(2,1) for i in range(4)] # 2 relevant
    rels3 = [genfinalcolumn(2,2) for i in range(3)] # 2 relevant

    data = irrels + rels1 + rels2 + rels3
    random.shuffle(data)

    result = []
    for fincol in data:
        qname = dummy_qname
        market = dummy_market
        details = arbnumgen()
        result.append(dict(zip(headers, (qname,market,details,fincol))))

    return result


def generate_dataframe():
    data = generate_data()
    return pandas.DataFrame.from_records(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = generate_dataframe()
    df.to_csv('test.csv')

    # from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
    # parsed = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('test.csv')
    # assert_frame_equal(parsed, df)
```

### Test solution

```
import pandas

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Read the dataframe
    typedict = { 'Query_Name' : str
               , 'Market' : str
               , 'Details': float }
    def fincolconverter(string):
        return eval(string)
    df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv',dtype=typedict, index_col=0,
                         converters={'Final_Column': fincolconverter})

    # Accumulator for new rows
    rowlist = []
    # Iterating over rows
    for ind, row in df.iterrows():
        # list in question
        data = row['Final_Column']
        # data count in the list
        datacount = len(data)
        if datacount < 2:
            # we pass the row as is and continue iteration
            rowlist.append(row)
            continue

        for dat in data:
            # make a duplicate
            newrow = row.copy()
            # change the relevant column with extracted data
            newrow['Final_Column'] = dat
            rowlist.append(newrow)

    # Create final dataframe
    finaldf = pandas.DataFrame(rowlist)

    # Reset the index, note that drop=True drops the old index instead of
    # creating a new column and moving it there.
    finaldf.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

    print(finaldf)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I wanted to duplicate those rows with multiple data points and then write out the duplicated data point in that row. I don't need a count- I need to flatten out the data points in the Final_Column so that each cell contains only 1 data point; if there are 2 points, then a second row is created as a duplicate of the first and contains the second data point.

Comment: I performed counting as an intermediate step. I am confused. Do you want to extract the datapoints in the Final_Column corresponding to different relevant data and insert them as separate rows? If it is so, your example is kind of misleading.

Comment: What I wanted is basically this: if the number of data points in final_column are greater than 1, duplicate that row and strip the original of its 2 data points; keep the first one in the original and put the second one in the second row.

Comment: I think I found out why I'm confused. In your 2nd example (showing how it should look like), at row 4 i think you wanted to write 'relevant_data2' instead of 'relevant_data1' and in row 21, you wanted to write 'relevant_data4' instead of 'relevant_data3'. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Harelephant, I included a different solution according to what you've described in my answer, it's under **Edit 1** section. Could you try it? I'll delete the original answer and remove the Edit tag after you clarify your examples and question.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response, I really appreciate your input. Will test this out and let you know my results ASAP

Comment: I implemented your code, but it seems that the line of code "data = row['Final_Column'] is returning for me the string type, not the actual data. So my final column has "<type str>" printed out into it.

Comment: @Harelephant: The python script I provided in the _Data generation_ section creates an example dataframe similar to yours and saves it as 'test.csv'. The script in '_Test solution_' section reads this csv, and runs the actual algorithm on it. I suggest you try it and see if it solves your actual problem. As to your second problem, that is _converting a list of dictionaries stored as strings to python list of dictionaries_, `your_dataframe['Final_Column'] = your_dataframe['Final_Column'].map(eval)` (see code in _Test solution_ for similar approach)